# perl how to catch and handle sigpipe

Tags: perl

I want to call a subroutine upon receiving sigpipe. I tried something like below:

```
$SIG{'PIPE'} = sub {
    print "Got sigterm \n";
};
```

However, I keep getting error:

```
Signal SIGPIPE received, but no signal handler set.
```

I can do `$SIG{'PIPE'} = 'IGNORE'` but how to call a subroutine

Comment: Look [here](http://perltricks.com/article/37/2013/8/18/Catch-and-Handle-Signals-in-Perl)

Comment: I think that message is only [issued](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git?a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=but+no+signal+handler+set) from threads. You may not have set the signal handler for that thread.

Comment: You code looks correct, something else must be going on in a piece that you have not shown. Can you post a complete example?

Comment: I was getting sigpipe from a thread. But put the handler outside of the thread. Thats why I was getting the error. Thanks to @ikegami

Comment: @Jens the link is dead, you can read the article here now: https://www.perl.com/article/37/2013/8/18/Catch-and-Handle-Signals-in-Perl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that message is only [issued](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git?a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=but+no+signal+handler+set) when using threads. I believe you the thread throwing the signal differs from the thread in which the signal handler was set.

Comment: Oooh, signals *and* threads? Have fun with that ;)
I.e. I'd really really advise not doing that.